# How to implement custom sort for koGrid?

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js, typescript, kogrid

**Data:**

16.00 hours
19.99 hours
210.46 hours
262.54 hours
303.19 hours
55.95 hours
60.07 hours
64.07 hours
7.95 hours

**What I want:**

I need to allow sorting for this king of data in koGrid (default feature by clicking grid header, asc or desc sort).

**Problem:**

The data is string so you might guess how it sorts out - by char codes.
What are my options? I found that a column can have sortFn assigned, something like this I guess?

[image]

**Code:**

```
this.gridOptions = {
            canSelectRows: false,
            showColumnMenu: false,
            showFilter: false,
            columnDefs: [

                { field: 'localizedName', displayName: 'Name' },
                {
                    field: 'localizedDuration', displayName: 'Duration',
                    sortFn: function (itemA: string, itemB: string) {
                        var numA = parseFloat(itemA);
                        var numB = parseFloat(itemB);

                        if (!numA && !numB)
                            return 0;
                        else if (!itemA && (itemA === undefined || itemA === null))
                            return 1;
                        else if (!itemB && (itemB === undefined || itemB === null))
                            return -1;

                        if (numA > numB)
                            return -1;
                        else if (numA < numB)
                            return 1;

                        return 0;
                    }
                },
            ],
            data: this.dataRows
        };
```

**Fiddle:**
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvey3znv/)

Comment: try adding a sample fiddle repro so its easy to look into it .

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/NMtsX/40/  it works fine not using any custom sort . fork this fiddle to explain your issue .

Comment: Forked, if you check, my data is strings formated with word "Hours" alognside number. Check the forked fiddle, it does not sort right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to modify your code like this

**View :**

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.myData = ko.observable([{
        hours: '113.02 hours'
    }, {
        hours: '13.01 hours'
    }, {
        hours: '303.01 hours'
    }, {
        hours: '33.01 hours'
    }]);

    self.gridOptions = {
        data: self.myData,
        columnDefs: [{
            field: 'hours',
            displayName: 'hours',
            sortFn(a, b) {
                if (!(a && b)) {
                    return -1;
                }
                var a1 = parseFloat(a.split(' ')[0]);
                var b1 = parseFloat(b.split(' ')[0]);
                if (a1 > b1) return 1;
                if (a1 < b1) return -1;
                if (a1 = b1) return 0;
            }
        }]
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new vm);
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/Ls112ecw/1/)**

Reference documentation available **[here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid)**